# How to install Ubuntu from 500GB external hard drive

Tags: system-installation

I have downloaded ubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso I want to install Ubuntu directly on my external HDD from my Windows 10 desktop
Can any one please provide me the steps I have read many articles related to this but not sure how to install

Comment: Can't be done from the Windows desktop. You must boot from the `.iso`.

Comment: Thanks @waltinator so I will need to make the live Ubuntu usb stick then connect external HDD and I can install Ubuntu on external HDD right?

Comment: You can install Ubuntu to whatever drives your hardware allows it to be written to, and booted from. Most machines allow a great amount of flexibility in this regard, some others do not however and we cannot provide meaningful answers as to what your machine may, or many not provide.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu: In Windows you can quickly install Ubuntu to an external drive using an Image file. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1255783/cannot-install-ubuntu-on-my-flash-drive/1255893#1255893 Some people might not consider this a secure way of installing Ubuntu, but I use it and think it is the future.

Comment: It is also possible to install Ubuntu from an internal drive to an external drive by using UNetbootin to make a temporary "Frugal" install to the internal drive. The next boot Ubuntu will start and can be used as an installer, See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250746/how-to-install-using-my-internal-hard-drive/1250798#1250798 You can also install Ubuntu using a Cell phone. I have also installed Ubuntu using my MP3 player.

Comment: See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130372/dual-booting-win-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-two-separate-physical-ssds/1130381#1130381) for a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

### Installing to External Drive Using only Internal Windows Drive

Both **Rufus** and **Etcher** will install Ubuntu Live to an External USB. Ubuntu Live can then be used to install Ubuntu to the same external drive.

In Rufus select "List USB Hard Drives"

In Etcher select the gear in the upper right hand corner, then select "Unsafe mode"

**Warning**: This will overwrite all data on the external drive.

Remember to unselect these options when done.

Disable internal drive before proceeding.

Once Ubuntu Live is installed to the external drive, boot it in the same BIOS/UEFI mode Windows uses, using the `toram` option.

Press `shift` as soon as the boot starts. Press `esc` then press `F6`, press `esc` again, then type a space and then type `toram`.

Once booted open Nautilus and enter `sudo umount -lrf /dev/sdxy` Where sdxy is the partition containing the running Live Ubuntu.

- Start Install Ubuntu.
- Select Language, click "Continue".
- Select Keyboard layout, click "Continue".
- Select Wireless network, click "Continue". (optional).
- Select installation preference and select "Download updates while installing Ubuntu", (optional), and Select "Install third-party software ...", click "Continue". (Optional).
- If asked about mounted partitions, select Yes, click "Continue".
- Do not use Advanced feature disk encryption for this install method.
- At "Installation type" select "Something else". (Full disk encryption is not working with flash drives).
- Select "Continue".
- Confirm target device for bootloader is correct.
- Select "New Partition Table".
- Click Continue on the drop down.
- Click "free space" and then "+".
- Select "Primary", "Size ..." = 4500 to 6000 MB, "Beginning of this space", Ext4, and Mount point = "/" then OK.
- Click Install now.
- Confirm partitions to be formatted if asked, click continue.
- Select your location. click "Continue".
- Insert your name, computer name, username, password and select
  if you want to log in automatically or require a password. - Click "Continue".
- Wait until install is complete.