# I need help installing encrypted Ubuntu on USB

Tags: usb, uefi, encryption, bios

I want to make a USB that is encrypted and has Ubuntu OS installed on it. I tried many different ways, but this is how far I came.

I found this post: [Installing Ubuntu on a LUKS encrypted USB thumb drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1255753/installing-ubuntu-on-a-luks-encrypted-usb-thumb-drive/newreg=aa3378c2ef99488b891a163bd91acb37)

I followed the guide but I don't know how to do the steps. I require assistance with the following tasks: booting in BIOS or UEFI Modes.

I've tried to find answers, but I'm not very smart at Linux, so I don't know what I'm doing. I just need some assistance.

BTW, another question is, after I finish the guide, will I be able to run the USB on, let's say, my other laptop, or only the PC it was installed on?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello. To start with what version of Ubuntu are you going to use?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply! Any version would do, but i installed the 20.04.4 (latest)

Comment: Would be a good idea to update the question with the additional info.

Comment: I wanted to write more but i don't know what to write more about, i'm clueless when it comes to Linux haha. What info would be needed? I just want to finish the guide that im trying to followed, im stuck at the part where it explains "Booting in BIOS/UEFI Modes". I dont know how to copy from partitions, find the files it wants to. I hope this could clear it out a bit more.

Comment: You can do a Full install to a USB drive and use **Advanced Features** to make it an encrypted install. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260830/create-encrypted-bootable-usb-without-overwriting-internal-disk

Comment: i want to do that, ill give it a shot i guess. but i would much more prefer to use the other guide that ive posted

Answer (score 0):

### Install Ubuntu as Encrypted USB

Oops, I see I wrote the link you point to.

- Unplug your internal drive, Plug in and boot a Live USB into the BIOS/UEFI mode you want the new install to boot with, then plug in the Target USB you want to install to.
- Click the desktop icon to install Ubuntu.
- Proceed with installation until you get to **Installation type**.
- Select **Advanced Features** and click **Use LVM... and Encrypt...**.
- Complete the installation.
- Plug in the internal drive, boot the USB and run `sudo update-grub`. If the version is 21.10 or earlier, any OS on the internal drive should be added to the new Ubuntu's GRUB boot menu.

Here is some info on making an encrypted Full install USB that boots in both BIOS and UEFI and should work on most Intel/AMD based computers. See: [How to Make BIOS/UEFI Flash Drive with Full Disk Encryption](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086309/how-to-make-bios-uefi-flash-drive-with-full-disk-encryption)

Let me know how I can assist.

Comment: thank you so much for this info, its kinda late right now so i will try it out tomorrow and tell you how it goes. Kudos to you dear friend!

Comment: hey, so i made the USB and now i need to make it UEFI compatible. Is there a easier guide to follow because i dont understand the one u mentioned

Comment: If you make your Live USB using **Rufus**, you can select **Partition scheme = GPT** and **Target system = UEFI**. This will make a Ubuntu full install USB that boots in UEFI mode only.